# How to notify other users of changes made to data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, wcf

We have an ASP.NET application which is used by many users. This application is using custom database. Whenever one user makes changes we save changes to custom database's audit table.

Now we need to notify other logged in users about this change... how can this be done ?

I am thinking about this solution but it might be overkill ?

- Create a sql trigger somehow whenever table is changed.. create a record in text file in file system
- create a web services to keep checking if anything new added to file system and if it did show notification to other users.

I am using filesystem because I don't want to kill sql.

Comment: Maybe an SQLDependency plus a websocket could do the job?

Comment: Because all changes go via your application, you can do the alert at the application level, and so be more reactive, and not involve SQL at all. Look into SignalR or similar for performing eventing to the user.

Comment: You could also look into Concurrency https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373(v=vs.110).aspx and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38299/How-To-Handle-Concurrency-in-LINQ-to-SQL if you are using Linq to SQL

Comment: @change i got the same situation but what i did is slightly same as your idea but i used with **SQL** .Here is my idea you need to create another table name it as `notification` table and when ever there is a change do a trigger and insert into that table with extra flag `Isnotified` by default keep this as `false` . so your web server will be picking from this table ans will show notification to the users based on the flag `Isnotified`, after sending the notification just change the `flag` . to be continued (1)

Comment: Keep it simple! Use SingnalR. When asp.net succcessfully saves / updates the data in the database (via WCF or midleware) Singnal R can update the connected clients with the new record update or added.

Comment: @change in this way you will be in sync with SQL and you are sending service outside the application (Generally we do it in a certain time frequency not linking with the application )  in this way we can customize our notification based on the Particular users(end)

Answer (score 0):

In this example I created a very simple WPF application with a grid, simulating some stocks value.

Let's start assuming the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stocks]( [Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [Price] [decimal](18, 0) NULL) GO INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'MCD', N'McDonald Corp', CAST(333 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'NKE', N'Nike Inc', CAST(240 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'DIS', N'Walt Disney Co', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'UTX', N'United Technologies Corp', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'MSFT', N'Microsoft Corp', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'PFE', N'Pfizer Inc', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'INTC', N'Intel Corp', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0))) INSERT [dbo].[Stocks] ([Code], [Name], [Price]) VALUES (N'KO', N'Coca Cola Co', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0))) GO
```

This table is constantly updated with new stock values. We want keep update our grid without use of any polling system. So, what we need is a notification coming from the database every time a record in the table has been changed.

We install the SqlTableDependency package from visual studio using the following command:

```
PM> Install-Package SqlTableDependency
```

Now we define a C# model mapping the interested table columns.

```
public class Stock { public decimal Price { get; set; } public string Symbol { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } }
```

As you can see, model's properties name can have a different table column name. In this case, we need a mapper to correclty bind the values:

```
var mapper = new ModelToTableMapper<Stock>(); mapper.AddMapping(model => model.Symbol, "Code");
```

Finally we create our SqlTableDependency:

```
_dependency = new SqlTableDependency<Stock>(_connectionString, "Stocks", mapper); _dependency.OnChanged += _dependency_OnChanged; _dependency.OnError += _dependency_OnError; _dependency.Start();
```

Below the complete code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window { private IList<Stock> _stocks; private readonly string _connectionString = "data source=.;initial catalog=TableDependencyDB;integrated security=True"; private readonly SqlTableDependency<Stock> _dependency; public Window1() { this.InitializeComponent(); this.McDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData(); this.Closing += Window1_Closing; var mapper = new ModelToTableMapper<Stock>(); mapper.AddMapping(model => model.Symbol, "Code"); _dependency = new SqlTableDependency<Stock>(_connectionString, "Stocks", mapper); _dependency.OnChanged += _dependency_OnChanged; _dependency.OnError += _dependency_OnError; _dependency.Start(); } private void Window1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) { _dependency.Stop(); } private void _dependency_OnError(object sender, TableDependency.EventArgs.ErrorEventArgs e) { throw e.Error; } private void _dependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<Stock> e) { if (_stocks != null) { if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None) { switch (e.ChangeType) { case ChangeType.Delete: _stocks.Remove(_stocks.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Symbol == e.Entity.Symbol)); break; case ChangeType.Insert: _stocks.Add(e.Entity); break; case ChangeType.Update: var customerIndex = _stocks.IndexOf(_stocks.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Symbol == e.Entity.Symbol)); if (customerIndex >= 0) _stocks[customerIndex] = e.Entity; break; } this.McDataGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { this.McDataGrid.Items.Refresh(); })); } } } private IEnumerable<Stock> LoadCollectionData() { _stocks = new List<Stock>(); using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) { sqlConnection.Open(); using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand()) { sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Stocks]"; using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()) { while (sqlDataReader.Read()) { var code = sqlDataReader.GetString(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Code")); var name = sqlDataReader.GetString(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Name")); var price = sqlDataReader.GetDecimal(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Price")); _stocks.Add(new Stock { Symbol = code, Name = name, Price = price }); } } } } return _stocks; } }
```

As you can see from the code, only an initial select is performed to retrieve and populate the grid. Subsequent updates are done using the SqlTableDependency event handler: its receives a model object containing info about the record changed that we use to update our cache.

you can also check [How can I notify my program when the database has been updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723551/how-can-i-notify-my-program-when-the-database-has-been-updated).

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, you could publish these changes to other users with help of traditional '*ModifiedOn*' column in table. The extra bit would be to have some logic which select and publish records those are changed within a given time frame.

You may pick a table which you want to track and add a new column say *ModifiedOn*; and then record a *TimeStamp* on this field as and when user change any given row.

Next step would be to write some logic which trigger every *x* minutes to see all modified rows in that table. You may persist the last execution time of your logic for faster search.

1. Your monitoring app check for all modified record from `sometime` to
   `current time`
2. Save current time after execution. This is to help with subsequent searches. Lets say you save this as *LastRunTime*
3. Your app shall wake up at *n*th minute from now and check for
   record modified from *LastRunTime* to now.
4. Overwrite *LastRunTime* value with now.