# Do an API show data in real time from database SQL with mvc5 and WebAPI

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have an api that queries the database and shows to list servers and their status on the screen, I would like that when a change occurs in the database this would be reflected on the screen, where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the application is the single entry to your database then you could do this with pure SignalR. When you save your changes in the code make sure to trigger a message on the hub which all subscribers will get and then make sure the client get/recieve the new data.

Example: `context.Clients.All.broadcastNotification("UserNotification", "new user added");`

**If** you have many entries to the database where changes can happen from more than just your application then you need to subscribe to your database changes and use SignalR to then update the clients. ADO.NET has something called *SqlDependency* which will notify your application when changes has been made, read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723551/how-can-i-notify-my-program-when-the-database-has-been-updated)

Answer (score 1):

Read about ddl trigger in SQL Server. You can add a trigger in your system to show that if something is changed in the database.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.105).aspx