# how to update(notify) DataGridView when data changes in the SQL database Table C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, dataset

I am working on the `Dataset` and `DataGridview` so far everything seems ok.

I can read data from the `SQL` table and show it in the `DataGridView`, I even can edit the values in the `DataGridView` directly and update the database without a problem.

my question is :

> if the data changes in the database directly from another source (not my app), how can my app get notified and update the `DataGridView` accordingly without refreshing the whole `DataGridView`?

Comment: [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server) is an option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I notify my program when the database has been updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723551/how-can-i-notify-my-program-when-the-database-has-been-updated)

Comment: @Crowcoder haven't used it, ill check it out

Comment: @stuartd is it the only way ?